# How can I completely erase a "read only" USB drive?

Tags: usb, permission, disk-format

I have a USB drive that appears to be stuck as a "read-only" device.

[image]

I have tried to format it as MS-DOS (FAT) Master Boot Record using Disk Utility, but I get the following

[image]

I also have followed all of the instructions indicated in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215262/dd-dev-disk4-permission-denied-error-when-making-liveusb-on-mac-os-x) to zero out the first sectors on the drive but I get the "Permission denied" error no matter what I do.

**Update:** I also have followed the instructions in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1019759/how-can-i-force-format-read-only-usb-drive-in-osx-el-capitan) to first force unmount the drive but still get "Permission denied".

[image]

Finally, when I check for permissions, I can see that I have no "writing" permissions whatsoever on the drive:

[image]

This may explain why I cannot format it. How can I solve this? Is there something that I am missing?

Note: I have recently successfully formatted several other usb-drives using disk utility alone so I believe that the usb ports on this computer are working properly.

Comment: Check here: https://superuser.com/questions/1019759/how-can-i-force-format-read-only-usb-drive-in-osx-el-capitan

Comment: @Udhy I just tried that solution, I still get "Permission denied" when trying to execute dd

Comment: Where do you get this USB Flash Drive and what's on it? If it came from HP with programs/documentation on it, then it's write protected from HP. Searching Google, I found many hits with a HP v220w, and other HP USB Flash Drives that were write protected. Only saw ways under Windows to make it writable.

Comment: @user3439894 I put several personal documents on it, and it was working properly up to some point where I could no longer write on it. I did not know that this was a known issue, perhaps you could point me towards a thread explaining how to make it writable again under Windows...